# How to replace all non-zero values from column in select?

Tags: sql

I need to replace non-zeros in column within select statement.

```
SELECT Status, Name, Car from Events;
```

I can do it like this:

```
SELECT (Replace(Status, '1', 'Ready'), Name, Car from Events;
```

Or using Case/Update.

But I have numbers from -5 to 10 and writing Replace or something for each case is not good idea.

How can I add comparasing with replace without updating database?

Table looks like this:

```
Status     Name    Car 
0          John    Porsche
1          Bill    Dodge
5          Megan   Ford
```

Comment: what is your expected output in this case?

Comment: Should you get ready for `-5` ?

Comment: You could write a function and write case statements in that function mapping the values you need in return for the no-zero value of a status column and simply call the function in the select query

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are usually highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Any null values if the Status column? Expected result?

Comment: Done with Case function, I simply wanted to replace all non-zeros more than 0 to ready, less than 0 to non ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard method is to use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 1 then 'Ready'
             else 'Something else'
        end) as status_string
from t;
```

I would instead recommend, though, that you have a status reference table:

```
create table statuses (
    status int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);

insert into statuses (status, name)
    values (0, 'UNKNOWN'),
           (1, 'READY'),
           . . .  -- for the rest of the statuses
```

Then use `JOIN`:

```
select t.*, s.name
from t join
     statuses s
     on t.status = s.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(status =1, 'Approved', 'Pending') FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: The <SQL> tag is for ANSI SQL, and IF is not in ANSI SQL.